# How to merge schema while loading avro in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro

I am trying to read avro files using https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro and the avro schema evolved over time. I read like this with mergeSchema option set to `true` hoping that it would merge schema itself but it didn't work.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("mergeSchema", "true").load('s3://xxxx/d=2015-10-27/h=*/')
```

What is the work around ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you resolve it? Is it a bug? Or could it be an unplemented feature?

Comment: How do you know _"but it didn't work."_? What's the error/exception?

Comment: @Zer001, it doesnt work for me neither, did you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Merging schema is not implemented for avro files in spark and there is no easy workaround. One solution would be to read your avro data file-by-file (or partition-by-partition) as separate data sets and then union those data sets. But that can be terribly slow.